# Oracle SUM function not working in Select clause

Tags: oracle, function, sum

I have the attached code below in which the sum(slice) column is giving me same results even if I don't use the SUM function. Can somebody help me fix the code?

Also need the following:

```
Currently, it is giving output as:

Task Name             Resource ID                  Slice Date            Slice Hours
abc                       123                         4/1                   8.50
abc                       123                         4/2                   7.50
abc                       123                         4/3                   8.50
```

I need output as:

```
Task Name          Resource ID                     Slice Date            Slice Hours
abc                       123                      4/1 – 4/30        <Total for the month>
xyz                       123                      4/1 – 4/30        <Total for the month>
```

```html
select distinct PCF.project_code as project_id, 
    PCF.project_name as project_name, 
    RCF.resource_id, 
    RCF.last_name || ' ' || RCF.first_name as resource_name,
    Tsh.slice_date as fact_date,
    sum(tsh.slice) "Total Slice",
    T.prname as TaskName, 
    task_info.phase_code as phase_code, 
    task_info.phase_name as phase_name, 
    task_info.task_sequence as task_outline
from prj_blb_slicerequests tsr
JOIN  prj_blb_slices tsh ON tsr.id = tsh.slice_request_id
JOIN prtimeentry TE ON tsh.prj_object_id = te.prid
JOIN prtimesheet TS ON TS.prid = TE.prtimesheetid 
 JOIN  prAssignment A ON TE.prassignmentid = A.prid
 JOIN prtask T ON A.prtaskid = T.prid 
JOIN nbi_resource_current_facts RCF ON TS.prresourceid = RCF.resource_id 
 JOIN nbi_project_current_facts PCF ON T.prprojectid = PCF.project_id
 JOIN prj_projects PP ON PCF.project_id = PP.prid
 JOIN (select task_id, phase_code, phase_name, task_name, task_sequence from cust_phase_rollup_v) task_info ON T.prid = task_info.task_id
where tsr.request_name = 'Daily Timeentry Actuals' 
  and tsh.slice > 0 
  and ts.prstatus < 5
  and tsh.slice_date >= to_date('1-MAY-14') 
  and tsh.slice_date <= to_date('31-MAY-14')
group by project_code, project_name, resource_id, RCF.last_name || ' ' || RCF.first_name, Tsh.slice_date, T.prname, task_info.phase_code,
  task_info.phase_name, task_info.task_sequence
order by project_id
```

Comment: Please don't repost questions...

Comment: sure, I have deleted the earlier question. Needed help on this urgently with some proper code changes help.

Answer (score 0):

2 problems:

1. You want results per month, not per day, so instead of just selecting the `slice_date`, you should convert that into month/year format.
2. To use an aggregate function, you need a corresponding `group by` in your query. You should group by all of the other columns you're selecting.

This should work (untested, though):

```
select distinct PCF.project_code as project_id, 
    PCF.project_name as project_name, 
    RCF.resource_id, 
    RCF.last_name || ' ' || RCF.first_name as resource_name,
    to_char(Tsh.slice_date, 'mm/yyyy') as fact_date,
    sum(tsh.slice) "Total Slice",
    T.prname as TaskName, 
    task_info.phase_code as phase_code, 
    task_info.phase_name as phase_name, 
    task_info.task_sequence as task_outline
from prj_blb_slicerequests tsr
JOIN  prj_blb_slices tsh ON tsr.id = tsh.slice_request_id
JOIN prtimeentry TE ON tsh.prj_object_id = te.prid
JOIN prtimesheet TS ON TS.prid = TE.prtimesheetid 
 JOIN  prAssignment A ON TE.prassignmentid = A.prid
 JOIN prtask T ON A.prtaskid = T.prid 
JOIN nbi_resource_current_facts RCF ON TS.prresourceid = RCF.resource_id 
 JOIN nbi_project_current_facts PCF ON T.prprojectid = PCF.project_id
 JOIN prj_projects PP ON PCF.project_id = PP.prid
 JOIN (select task_id, phase_code, phase_name, task_name, task_sequence from cust_phase_rollup_v) task_info ON T.prid = task_info.task_id
where tsr.request_name = 'Daily Timeentry Actuals' 
  and tsh.slice > 0 
  and ts.prstatus < 5
  and tsh.slice_date >= to_date('1-MAY-14') 
  and tsh.slice_date <= to_date('31-MAY-14')
  group by PCF.project_code, 
           PCF.project_name, 
           RCF.resource_id, 
           RCF.last_name || ' ' || RCF.first_name,
           to_char(Tsh.slice_date, 'mm/yyyy'),
           T.prname, 
           task_info.phase_code, 
           task_info.phase_name, 
           task_info.task_sequence
  order by PCF.project_code
```

Comment: if I use to_char(Tsh.slice_date, 'MONTH-YY') as fact_date, it is giving me the below error:
"not a Selected expression"

Comment: any other help please? can somebody modify the code for me? I am unable to.

Comment: see the amended answer.. your order by was in the wrong place, and was ordering by a column `project_id` that isn't in the select list. You can't use aliases in your where/order.group clauses.